# Android check if an int is in an interval + switch statement

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, integer-division

I'm displaying the user score  "right/tries" (es. 10/100) but I want to display it as % (es. 10%). Moreover I want it to be green if the score >= 90%, blue if the score is between 60% and 90% and red otherwise. With my code the score is green if the score is 100%, otherwise is red. It's never blue. (if I minimize the app and go back, sometimes is even black, the default value from xml).

My class call the changemyColor function in this way

```
 ....
int holderRight = sharedPrefs.getInt("Right", 0);
int holderTries = sharedPrefs.getInt("Tries", 0);
if ( holderTries != 0) { // to avoid n/0
changemyColor(holderRight,holderTries);
}
```

and this is the function

```
       public void changemyColor(int right, int tries) {
       TextView tvId = (TextView) findViewById(com.example.somma.R.id.score_field);
       int pino = 0; 

       double value = ((right / tries)*100) ;
       tvId.setText(getString(R.string.Score_capital) + sharedPrefs.getInt("Right", 0) + getString(R.string.Score_of) + sharedPrefs.getInt("Tries", 0));
       if (value >= 80) {
           pino = 1;
       } else if (value < 80 & value >= 30) {
               pino = 2;       
       } else if (value < 30) {
           pino = 3;
       }

       switch (pino){
       case 1:
           tvId.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
           break;
       case 2:
           tvId.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
           break;
       case 3:
           tvId.setTextColor(Color.RED);
           break;
       }       

   }
```

I also changed the code to

```
blabla.setText(value + " " + right + "/" + tries);
```

And got as output

```
"1.0 1/1"
"0.0 1/2"
"0.0 2/3"
"0.0 3/4"
"0.0 4/5"
"0.0 5/6"
"0.0 6/7"
"0.0 7/8" 
"0.0 8/9"
"0.0 9/10"
```

I think I'm doing something wrong in the division line but I can't figure it out alone. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: integer division returns integer values

Comment: I didn't know that! It seems I still lacks basics. You solved my problem. Thank you very much!
I changed the function to
public void changemyColor(double uno, double due)
and now everything works as a charm.

Comment: @pinolo That's not the most appropriate fix: tries and right are integer values, and should stay integer values. Instead, use `double value = ((double) right / tries)`.

Comment: did you want to use `&` instead of `&&` in your else clause : `else if (value < 80 & value >= 30) ` ?! there is a difference between the two operators !

Comment: Yes I used & instead of && on purpose but now I realize it doesn't make much sense. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's mobile, in case you wanted to still use `int` to use less resources on the device, (after realising that integer division is the default when using integers), you could perform the multiplication first so that you don't get rounded to 0:

```
int value = (right*100) / tries;
```

It won't be very accurate but you do have a range of values you're checking by anyway. Just a thought.

Comment: I don't need that degree of accuracy so your solution is perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

if you want the accurate result you have to use

```
double value=(right*100)/(double)tries
```

Comment: Can you explain me why right doens't have to be casted on (double)?
edit: Ok I got it reading @Ozzy 's answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to read my post and write your answer. I wish I could chose 2 best answers.